# What are the types of delivery status messages provided by AWS SMS? And what do they mean?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, sms

I created a module which imports daily usage of SMS csv files to laravel and analyzes it to track all the failed SMS recipient's phone number and then blacklists the phone number so as not to send SMS to the same number again. I checked this against success message like:

```
if($status != "Message accepted by phone carrier"){
    //do blacklist and stuff
}
```

But I soon found out that one of the numbers that I frequently used for testing (and which is valid) also got blacklisted. The status was `The recipient is currently unavailable` something like this. There are other status messages such as `Blocked as spam by phone carrier`. It must mean that sometimes if a phone is switched off or out of network range for some time, AWS will mark it as failed. But I don't know what these status messages mean to make a concrete decision whether to blacklist the numbers or not.

Does anyone know all the (or at least important) status messages and what they mean? I searched the AWS forums but found nothing there.

Comment: There's a list at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html#sms_stats_delivery_fail_reasons.

Comment: Thanks so much, also the messages are quite self-explanatory.